# HTTP Post Login failing

Tags: http, authentication, swift

I'm writing a simple log in to website, navigate to page and parse app for iOS. I've managed to generate a post request, but it doesn't seem to want to log in. I don't know why it could be failing, because I get status 200. Admittedly I get this even if I deliberately enter wrong credentials. Any ideas? (code is in Swift)

```
    var url = NSURL(string:"https://www.example.com/ps/signin.html")
    var request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: url)
    request.HTTPMethod = "POST"
    var dataString = "timezoneOffset=-600&userid1=xxx&userid=xxx&pwd=xxx&x=31&y=12"
    let data = (dataString as NSString).dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)
    request.HTTPBody = data
    var connection = NSURLConnection(request: request, delegate: self, startImmediately: false)
    println("sending request : \(request)")
    connection.start()
```

So I get a response back, with status 200, and seemingly the html code for the login page again.

Comment: Look at a login request sent by a web browser. Then look at the request sent by your above code. How do they differ?

Comment: I got the request string from the login request, didn't check the other headers though. I'll give that a quick look.

Comment: Yeah, I mean the whole request. The body is just one part. I use a proxy (like [Charles](http://www.charlesproxy.com/)) to compare all aspects of requests. Or even http://requestb.in/

Comment: With Charles all I can see are CONNECTs, no POSTs or useful information? And request.in I just get ok.

Comment: is this useful? <form id="login" onsubmit="signin(document.login)" method="post" name="login" action="/psp/ps/?cmd=login&amp;languageCd=ENG" autocomplete="on">

Comment: Maybe you should read a little more about how both those tools work... With Charles you'll need to enable SSL for the right host. And with requestb.in you will want to examine the request you sent to it on the requestb.in website.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are POSTing to the login form: `https://www.example.com/ps/signin.html`. You need to `POST` to the same place the HTML form posts to, namely: `https://www.example.com/psp/ps/?cmd=login&amp;languageCd=ENG`

Try changing your URL:

```
var url = NSURL(string:"https://www.example.com/psp/ps/?cmd=login&amp;languageCd=ENG")
```

Comment: this gives me a more promising return, but it seems to be give me an intermediate processing page, never the destination. but thats another issue, thanks.

Comment: More information about the server you're attempting to log into would be helpful, but this isn't really a Swift question anymore. It might help you to watch the network requests in your browser as you log in through the web form - Chrome, Firefox and Safari all have the ability to do this with their Network Inspector tools.